# Content Security Policy in manifest v3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

`Refused to load the script 'https://sbfse.com/analytics.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

I got this error in chrome extension manifest v3
How Can I solve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's no solution other than including the script inside the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Remotely hosted code is no longer allowed in Chrome extension **Manifest v3**; an extension can only execute JavaScript that is included within its package.
The solution is for you is to place the analytics.js file inside the Chrome extension.

Source: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#feature-summary